# jQuery if no image show a random image from array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have 2 templates and have 2 classes apped to the body tag and am trying to have if the template body has only the class africa show on the of images from the AFimages array but if the template body has the 2 classes africa and centrala show the images from the CAimages array but only if there is not an image already there.

It works for one but cant get it to do it for the body.africa.centrala if statement.

```
var AFimages = [
    '/images/LexMundiWebsite/images_AfricaBanner/1.jpg',
    '/images/LexMundiWebsite/images_AfricaBanner/2.jpg',
    '/images/LexMundiWebsite/images_AfricaBanner/3.jpg',
    '/images/LexMundiWebsite/images_AfricaBanner/4.jpg'
];
if ($('body.africa .header-img').length) { // implies *not* zero  

} else {
    $('<div class="row"><div class="twelve columns header-img"><img src="' + AFimages[Math.floor(Math.random() * AFimages.length)] + '"></div></div>').insertAfter('.top-nav-default-africa');
}
var CAimages = [
    '/images/LexMundiWebsite/images_CentralAmericaBanner/1.jpg',
    '/images/LexMundiWebsite/images_CentralAmericaBanner/2.jpg',
    '/images/LexMundiWebsite/images_CentralAmericaBanner/3.jpg',
    '/images/LexMundiWebsite/images_CentralAmericaBanner/4.jpg'
];
if ($('body.africa.centrala .header-img').length) { // implies *not* zero  

} else {
    $('<div class="row"><div class="twelve columns header-img"><img src="' + AFimages[Math.floor(Math.random() * AFimages.length)] + '"></div></div>').insertAfter('body.africa.centrala .top-nav-default-africa');
}
```

Comment: can you add the html as well/ a jsfiddle?

Comment: I think i have it figured out. If i switch the order and call the  if ($('body.africa.centrala .header-img') and then the if ($('body.africa .header-img') it seems to work. Not sure if this is the best most effective way though.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off using the onerror call on the original images.

Original image:

```
<img src="notvalid.png" onerror="randomimg" />

<script>
var AFimages = [
    '/images/LexMundiWebsite/images_AfricaBanner/1.jpg',
    '/images/LexMundiWebsite/images_AfricaBanner/2.jpg',
    '/images/LexMundiWebsite/images_AfricaBanner/3.jpg',
    '/images/LexMundiWebsite/images_AfricaBanner/4.jpg'
];

function RandomXToY(min,max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function randomimg(){
  this.src=AFimages[RandomXToY(1,4)];
}
</script>
```